# Grid results being rendered horizontally, not vertically

Tags: html, css

So my results are only supposed to be rendering across two columns in the grid, however, they are being rendered horizontally instead.

My CSS and the screenshot is attached outlining what the result currently is, vs what I want to achieve. Any thoughts on how I could allow these results to be similar to the desired view in the screenshot below?

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 16px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(odd) {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.grid-item:nth-last-child(-n + 2):nth-of-type(odd),
.grid-item:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" id="Submit">
  <div class="inner-form">
    <div class="input-field first-wrap">
      <div class="svg-wrapper">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                      <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16  "></path>
                  </svg>
      </div>
      <input id="search" type="url" name="url" placeholder="Paste here" required/>
    </div>

    <div class="input-field second-wrap">
      <button id="button" class="btn-search" onclick="searchIt()" value="press" type="submit">SEARCH       </button>
      <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn-search">SEARCH</button> -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <p id="errorMessage">Yikes!</p>

</form>
```

EJS Template

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid grid-item">
          <div class=“Countries>
              <img alt="" src= "<%= country.icon %>" /> <%= country.name %>
          </div>
  
          <div class ="Category">

          <% country.categories.forEach(function(cat){ %>
              <%= cat.name %>
          <% }); %>
    
          </div>
   </div>
```

[image]

Comment: please also add your HTML as a runnable code snippet (ctrl + m). However if you want to use the below each other the change either the placement direction or not use `1fr 1fr` which causes a 2 column placement.

Comment: @tacoshy HTML added. What do you mean don't use `1fr 1fr`, is that not what I want based on the desired result?

Comment: sorry my mistake I got confused by the picture thought you want them below eachother instead of next to each other. However With the code provided, I still cant reproduce the issue. You need to add sufficient code that outputs the error. otherwise we have to make assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
}

.grid-item {
  padding: 16px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(4),
.grid-item:nth-child(odd),
.grid-item:nth-child(8){
  border-right: none;
}

.grid-item:nth-last-child(-n+3){
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">Country Name</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Country Name</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Country Name</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Country Name</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Country Name</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Country Name</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Country Name</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Country Name</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Country Name</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Country Name</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Country Name</div>
</div>
```

Comment: With this thought wouldn't it only output 8 values? I do not know how many values will be returned as it is based on a search

Comment: @KyleUSA if you don't know the number of returned values, you can't do this with CSS alone.

Comment: What's the best way to do this in Javascript? To provide more context, I am using an ejs template

Comment: @KyleUSA it's a somewhat complicated problem. You'd need to find the number of grid-items with Javascript and then do some math and apply CSS borders via Javascript

Comment: Any help or insight you can provide would be helpful. I really need to hit this particular UI

Comment: @KyleUSA actually, are there always four in a column? If so, see my edit, this will work regardless of number of items

Comment: It still renders horizontally. I have also included my EJS template. Maybe that might provide some more context? Thanks for all your help. Greatly appreciated

Comment: @KyleUSA make sure the HTML and CSS look exactly like mine. The element with `display:grid` should be the parent, with the `grid-item` elements as direct children, containing the `Country Name`. If that doesn't work, maybe try posting a new question with a runnable example that produces the problem. Sorry I couldn't help further!

Comment: Yea still did not work. Here is a reproductive sample that works to fit the format I want. However the data is the same on either side. Any idea on how I could alter this? https://codepen.io/SteveyUSA/pen/yLVyomJ

Comment: @KyleUSA sorry man, I've got other stuff to do. If you post a new question, be sure to post the resulting HTML, not the EJS templates.